# javascript array as a list of strings (preserving quotes)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I've got an array of strings.  When I use .toString() to output it the quotes are not preserved.  This makes it hard to build the mysql query using an "in".  Consider the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column IN ('item1','item2','item3','item4')

toString is returning: IN (item1,item2,item3,item4)
```

There must be a simple fix I am overlooking here.

Comment: You are preparing a MySQL query in JavaScript? ... mmm ... SQL injection

Comment: are you using server side javascript?

Comment: Yes, unless this just a quick prototype, you should be aware that forming SQL on the client is essentially giving anyone complete access to your database. Doesn't matter if it's over HTTPs, the user can just open the debugger and inject away.

Comment: Sorry to spoil your fun on sql injection. I have an internal full text search stack that is returning to me indexes of records I need to lookup in mysql.  Node_Mysql has a bug which prevents arrays from being properly passed in so I was looking for a work around.  I ended up finding a patch that has just not yet found its way to the core: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/126

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The quotes aren't preserved because they're not actually part of the string value, they're just necessary to indicate string literals in your code.

So, don't use `toString()`. Instead, one way to do it is as follows:

```
var arr = ['item1','item2','item3','item4'];

var quotedAndCommaSeparated = "'" + arr.join("','") + "'";

// quotedAndCommaSeparated === "'item1','item2','item3','item4'"
```

The [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method returns a string that is all of the array elements concatenated into a single string with an (optional) separator between each item. So if you specify a separator that includes the quotation marks and commas you just have to manually append a starting and ending quote for the first and last item (respectively).

(And *please* tell me you're not using client-side JavaScript to form your SQL.)

EDIT: to allow for an empty array, include a default value for the resulting string, otherwise (as pointed out by missingno) the string would be `"''"`:

```
var newString = arr.length === 0 ? "" : "'" + arr.join("','") + "'";
// default for empty array here ---^^
```

(Might be more appropriate to have an `if (arr.length===0)` to take some other action rather than running the SELECT statement.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  And no, I'm not building some honeypot for those sql injection rats to come exploit.

Comment: What should be the correct behaviour with an empty array? Empty quotes (`"''"`) or empty string? (`""`)

Comment: @missingno - Good point. I'm not sure what would be needed given the result is getting concatenated into an SQL string - might be better not to run the SELECT statement at all. Still, easy to fix - I'll update my answer...

Comment: I spent 2 hours and this answer was so close to what I needed lol -- Anyway, I was trying to preserve the quotes from an array, so that I could put everything into CSV format and use commas for some of the text. I got this by using this:

csv += '"' + row.join('","')  + '"';

Comment: This would throw a syntax error if the item contains a quotation (or apostrophe) inside. Make sure to preprocess each item. For example, putting double apostrophe for postgres.

Comment: @massanishi - Simply forming the joined string from an array wouldn't cause a JS error, but yes, going on to use that string in an SQL statement would give an SQL error if the items had embedded apostrophes so you're right that each item should be preprocessed if they might contain apostrophes.

Comment: The previous answer by Lukasz is better because it will work fine even if `arr` of items is empty. This answer is error prone.

Answer (score 17):

Use `Array.map` to wrap each element with quotes:

```
items.map(function(item) { return "'" + item + "'" }).join(',');
```

The code gets simpler with ES6 features - arrow functions and template strings (implemented in node.js 4.0 and higher):

```
items.map(i => `'${i}'`).join(',');
```

You may also use whitelisting to prevent SQL injections:

```
const validItems = new Set(['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']);

items
   .filter(i => validItems.has(i))
   .map(i => `'${i}'`)
   .join(',')
```

Comment: minor improvement: you can call `join()` without parameters because by default it joins using `,`

Answer (score 7):

```
let keys = ['key1','key2']
let keyWithQoutes = keys.map((it) => {return `'${it}'`})
let sql = `SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE id IN (${keyWithQoutes})`
console.log(sql)
```

output:  "SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE id IN ('key1','key2')"

Answer (score 5):

The simple fix is adding the quotes yourself

```
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    items[i] = "'" + items[i] + "'";
}

var list_with_quotes = items.join(",");
```

Do note that I completely ignore SQL injection issues here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify` and join them

```js
["hello", "there", 21, 32]
    .map(entry => JSON.stringify(entry))
    .join(",");
```

returns

```
"hello","there",21,32
```

Answer (score -1):

**you can also use string literal and join**

```
var arr = ['item1','item2','item3','item4'];

var quotedAndCommaSeparated = `${arr.join(",")}`;
```

Answer (score -2):

Store the quotes:

```
var names = ["'item1'","'item1'","'item3'"];
alert('IN (' + names[1] + ')'); // IN ('item1')
```