# How to preserve quotes on values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, stringify

I have to redo the functionality of JSON.stringify for a class and I am stuck...

If I am passed an array, I need to return the exact array as a string. However, when I return the array, it strips the quotations off of any values that are strings. For example:

```
var arr = [8, "hello"];
var addQuotes = function(arr){
            return ('[' + arr + ']');
        }
addQuotes(arr);
//"[8, hello]"
```

However, I need it to return:

```
"[8, "hello"]"
```

How do I preserve the quotation marks on array values?

Comment: You need to look at the values one at a time, and if given a string, you add quotation marks to the output for that value.

Comment: there are no quotation marks. This isn't really JSON.stringify either. That will require some more code

Comment: That's because you're using the array in a string context, and JS will strip off the quotes when stringifying. `x = [1,"hello"]; y = '' + x` -> `[1,hello]`. building json isn't just a simple matter of slapping some text together. You're literally building Javascript code (with a much stricter syntax), and MUST build syntactically valid JS

Comment: ...and by the way, if you're replicating JSON data, you don't want those outer single quotes. that would not be valid JSON.

Comment: @MarcB: It doesn't strip the quotes. The quotes are not in the data to begin with.

Comment: @user2415266 — They're string literal delimiters, they can't be escaped. That would be a syntax error.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483179/javascript-array-as-a-list-of-strings-preserving-quotes

Comment: squint: maybe not internally, but a string literal must ALWAYS be quoted. JS knows that 'hello' is a string, so no quotes are stored internally, but OP isn't doing "internal" stuff. That string is going "outside" and therefor **MUST** be wearing appropriate "clothing".

Comment: @MarcB: The OP is creating JSON data, not a JavaScript string literal. So the outer quotes should not be there. As to stripping the quotes, that's confusing. It makes it sound like the quotes *are* part of the data. That's the only reason I mention it.

Comment: squint: json data **IS** javascript. It's not JS's job to realize that the string it's building is destined to be a json string. That's OP's job.

Comment: @MarcB: JSON data ***IS*** JSON data. If the result has outer single quotes, it's not JSON data. Let's not conflate visual syntax with actual data produced. Because, as you said, it's not JS's job to know what is being produced, but rather the OP's job, the result should not have outer quotes. That would only be if the OP *wanted* to treat it like JavaScript, like with `eval` for example.

Comment: @MarcB You're right, that's the OP's job, and manually prefixing the JSONString by adding `"'" +` is a poor way to designate that the string is meant to be JSON, especially since it makes it invalid JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recursive JSON.stringify implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333101/recursive-json-stringify-implementation)

Comment: @MarcB I edited the outer quotes for valid JSON. My apologies. New to JSON.

Comment: @CarolynCommons: That doesn't make it valid. The outer quotes would be used to initialize JSON text inside a JavaScript program. The actual, valid JSON would not have any outer quotes. Since you're not being asked to create a JavaScript string that would represent JSON data when evaluated, but rather JSON data itself, the outer quotes should not be there.

Comment: You can see this [JSON polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Polyfill)

Comment: Sadly, this is actually one of the better questions on this site and it's getting thumbed down for some reason. Here's a [*simple* example](https://jsfiddle.net/1zqmyf08/1/) of how to produce JSON data for your given array input. It doesn't cover all data types, and doesn't escaped nested quotes, but it should give you a basic idea.

Comment: @CarolynCommons deleted my answer as I had misinterpreted your question +1 for the question though :)

Comment: @CarolynCommons: json is basically the right-hand side of a Javascsript variable assignment: `var foo = [1,2,3]`, so the json here is `[1,2,3]`. That means your json generator has to generate EXACTLY the same text, which means a string in that array has to be quoted. you don't just slap quotes around the array definition: `'[1,hello]'` may be  valid javascript string, but it's an illegal json construct. an array encoded to JSON and stored as a string would be `var json = '[1,"hello"]'`

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation on JSON, @MarcB.

Comment: @CarolynCommons: That's actually a misleading explanation of what JSON is. JSON is textual data. It doesn't have anything specific to do with JavaScript, except that its syntax is derived from syntax used in JS programs. Explanations like that are what cause people to add quotes around the outside. An actual visualization of JSON using UTF encoded characters could look like: `[1,"hello"]`. Those who don't understand the difference between JSON and JS may claim that's a JS Array. In fact, it's just syntax. Where and how it's used determines *what* it is.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this code :

```
var arr = [8, "hello"];
var arrString = arr.map(x => typeof x === 'string' ? "\"" + x + "\"" : x);
result = "\"[" + arrString.join(", ") + "]\""
console.log(result); // ) "[8, "hello"]"
```

Comment: It's not a polyfill but it will provide a partial implementation that works for the given data in the question, except that the outer single quotes make it invalid as JSON data. They shouldn't be there.

Comment: But the outer double quotes don't make sense either. You're confusing how you'd represent JSON data in a JS program with the JSON data itself. If you had a program that had `var j = '[8, "hello"]'`, then `j` would contain JSON text, notably *without* the outer quotes. `j[0] === "'"; // false j[0] === "["; // true`. So the *actual* JSON representation would start with `[` and end with `]`.

Comment: It's true but it's conform to the specification of this post

Comment: What the OP requires is a valid JSON result. Because of the common misunderstanding of what JSON *is* and how it is distinct from JavaScript, the OP thought it would be necessary to add outer quotes, but that was a mistake.

Comment: Anyway, I think Carolyn should rewrite what she is expecting as a return

Comment: That would indeed reduce the confusion, though she pretty clearly stated that the assignment is to re-create the output of `JSON.stringify`. I think people get confused because if they do `JSON.stringify([8, "Hello"])` in the console, it'll show outer quotes, which of course isn't actually part of the data either. Ultimately, she's going to need a function that examines the type like you're doing, generates the correct output, and makes a recursive call for Arrays and Objects.